# How to resolve problem with webpack in angular universal project?

Tags: angular-universal

when i am converting angular project to universal. webpack is installed automatically then when i'm trying to build for ssr it is showing message that webpack-cli and webpack-command both are installed. then i uninstalled one of then still it is not working. also node dist/server command is not recognized by angular-cli.

please help..

I tried to uninstall webpack-cli.

× ｢webpack｣: Flags were specified that were not recognized:

--colors  Not sure what you mean there

Please check the command executed.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sample-project@0.0.0 compile:server: `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample-project@0.0.0 compile:server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gpw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-13T05_17_21_908Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sample-project@0.0.0 build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample-project@0.0.0 build:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gpw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-13T05_17_21_995Z-debug.log

Comment: edit your question add some codes , show package.json and what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i want to convert my angular project to universal and generate sitemap for that